# Xamarin Listview Binding not working

Tags: listview, xamarin

I'm trying to get simple binding to work on a Xamarin Listview without any luck.
I don't get any errors. I just get a ListView with maybe 10 or so empty rows.

Here's the XAML code I'm using.

```
  <ContentView.Content >
<StackLayout>      
  <ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

        <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding TName}"/>
            <Label Text ="{Binding Num, StringFormat='${0}'}"/>
            </StackLayout>                        
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class TestView : ContentView
{
    public TestView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView.BindingContext = this;
    }

    public static ObservableCollection<Test> myItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Test>(new[] 
            {
                new Test() { TName = "Item 1", Num = 1 },
                new Test() { TName = "Item 2", Num = 2 },
                new Test() { TName = "Item 3", Num = 3 },
                new Test() { TName = "Item 4", Num = 4 },
            });
        }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string TName { get; set; }
    public int Num { get; set; }
}
```

I'm starting to believe Xamarin isn't my friend :(.

Comment: this.BindingContext = this;

Comment: Thanks Jason! I had to add that and changed removed the static from myItems.
If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it right.

Answer (score 1):

Change as following, it is working

```
    public ObservableCollection<Test> myItems
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Test>(new[]
            {
            new Test() { TName = "Item 1", Num = 1 },
            new Test() { TName = "Item 2", Num = 2 },
            new Test() { TName = "Item 3", Num = 3 },
            new Test() { TName = "Item 4", Num = 4 },
            }
            );
        }
    }
```